# Интеграция через SAOP

Tags: php, soap

Такая задача у нас: периодически  (например раз в 10 мин) они должны попадать на сайт.
Т.е. сайт никаких данных в 1С не отправляет, только принимает, если ему отправят.

Стандартного обмена нет. Нужна реализация именно на soap.

Хотелось бы понять как это работает, перед тем как приступить к работе:

1. Кто должен выступать в роли сервера, а кто в роли клиента? Насколько я  понимаю сайт в роли сервера будет, 1С клиент?
2. Где должен лежать SOAP сервер? Можно его на сайте разместить в некую папку?

Answer (score 0):

1. Т.к. в 1С скорее всего нет встроенного сервера, то да, скорее всего сам сайт будет выступать в роли сервера.
2. SOAP сервер может быть размещен в любой папке на сервере к которой будет доступ у клиента